# input a complex number and return it as a str

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to learn in python how to take int or complex number and return a string just like this example:

I cannot use any libraries and it must return a string as shown above with ' ' . 
Please help

Comment: How is `15+15i` an int?

Comment: 15+15i is not valid python. What are you planning to send exactly?

Comment: 15+15j would be a valid python complex number. In such case you can use something like this: `convert = lambda x: str(x).strip(')').strip('(')`

Comment: in python, for complex number, we use `j` instead of `i`, so your number should be `15+15j`

Comment: can you make a function that would take a real and a complex part?

Comment: @Cyber `real_part = complex_number.real` and `imagine_part = complex_number.imag`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea:

```
def convert(a, b=None):
    if b:
        return "'{}+{}i'".format(a,b)
    else:
        return "'{}'".format(a)
```

Comment: Hi, it only returns -5 but not '-5'

Comment: For me it returns a string, if i do [type](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-type-function/)(convert(-5)) i get an str type as an output. Do you need quotation marks to be printed?

Comment: Yes I have done similar to what you have implemented  however, the output needs to be represented as '-5' with the quotation marks which I don't understand how to do.

Comment: Thank you, yes it has to

Comment: It returns as '(5+5j)' but it has to return as '5+5j'

Comment: def convert(a, b=None):
    if b:
        return "'{}+{}i'".format(a,b)
    else:
        return "'{}'".format(a)
print(convert(((5+5j))))
    
    out put : '(5+5j)'

Comment: When you define the function it takes two arguments, the real part and the complex part to get what you need use it as print(convert(5, 5)) and it will print '5+5i' if you want to replace the 5i to 5j just replace the i to a j in the first part of the if statement. If your number doesn't have the complex part just put one number into the function

Comment: I don't understand, could you please explain more .Thank you for your help

Comment: Okay, so first we define a function `def convert(a, b=None):`, this function takes two arguments, but it can take only one since there is "b=None" this means that if the second argument isn't given b will be None. Then we test `if b:`, this will look if b exists since if something is None it's false. Then we're returning a string `"'{}+{}i'".format(a, b)` this will return a string with quotations and your numbers in it. On the other hand if b wasn't given, aka the second argument then we will go to the else part of the if statement and

Comment: there's the return keyword that returns the first argument as a string `"'{}'".format(a)`. It may be confusing what is [.format](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-format-function/) so i recommend you look it up.

Comment: I completely understand what you are saying but when I use the function with this input (5+5j) it returns '(5+5j)' and I want it to return '5+5j' instead, can you guide me through how to do that please?

Comment: So when you put (5+5j) into it it treats it as one argument and it print stat argument with quotations around it. For this to print you wold need to pass two numbers into the function the first one being the real part and the second one the complex part.
Could you paste me the line of code where you get the (5+5j)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right you can just explicitly convert ir by using the str() method, like so:

```
def convert_to_str(complex_num):
    return str(complex_num)
```

If I misunterstood, please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Use [str()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_str.asp) function

```
return str(15+15i)
```